# How to find a script that modifies a file on startup

Tags: file, unix, path, startup, opensuse

I am currently on a machine where i have to change an existing script.
Nobody knows what path are.

I only know that modifies a file at startup , and it expects to have internet to do.

I try to find it with lsof but it looks like it is not enough "fast". It shows me nothing. I try to do with wireshark if he would send something, but nothing too.

I try to search with grep but nothing conclusive.

The machine is under OpenSuse x64 and i can be root.

Anyone have a solution for me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You know the name of the file that is modified?

Comment: Yes, eventually we may assume that the modified script is /etc/ foo, i can't access it without root.

Comment: Just to be clear - what is the name of the file that is modified? And, you are having trouble finding what script modifies that file? What do you mean by "Nobody knows what path are"?

Comment: In detail, my school installs the same distribution for everyone . In this distribution of school sets their script that prevents some modification . But at $ 1,500 for a machine , I would like to make some changes . I noticed that if I changed the password for the root, the script has set new password partner after the conditions I have described above.

So / etc/passwd and /etc/shadow

Comment: Did you rule out remote command by pulling out the network cables?

Comment: You mean to turn off the network?
While the network is off, the password is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

Rc files or profile files are used to run commands on startup(depending on login or non login shells). These could be Generally in /etc - global and in home directory for user specific  setting.

Have your considered checking contents of /etc/bashrc or /etc/bash.bashrc or profile?  What did you grep for?

Comment: Yes, I look into it but I have not found . I " grep -Rn name_of_modified_file 2>/dev/null"

And nothing in my bashrc separate aliases and env var.